# How to invoke a xamlx-workflow in an Azure website?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, workflow-foundation-4, azure-web-app-service

I'm experimenting with the new Azure Websites Preview in SDK 1.7 and I'm trying to invoke a WCF workflow in a xamlx-file I've put i a folder at the root.

Everything is working just fine in the emulator on my localhost but in the cloud i just get the standard error saying `"The resource cannot be found."` when I try to browse it.

What do I have to do to invoke the xamlx-workflow?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to access the xamlx file? And also the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: I'm trying to browse the definition. There's no stack trace, I'm getting the IIS The resource cannot be found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using XAMLX WorkFlow activity service will, you would need to add a WCF service to expose as service so clients can consume it.

For example you have StockPriceService.xamlx as your WorkFlow activity then just add a WCF service to your application and set the SVC to use XAMLX as below:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="StockPriceService.xamlx" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activities.Activation.WorkflowServiceHostFactory,System.ServiceModel.Activation,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"%>
```

I have explained this process in my latest blog [WorkFlow (XAMLX) Service Activity with WCF Service in Windows Azure Websites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/21/workflow-xamlx-service-activity-with-wcf-service-in-windows-azure-websites.aspx).

Comment: Do you know why it only works in the emulator? It's a bit confusing if it works on localhost but not in production, especially when learning new technologies.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in the emulator and it doesn't work when you deploy to the cloud it could be that the file is not included in the package.

Could you connect to your instance through Remote Desktop and take a look in the **E:\sitesroot\0** folder? Can you see the **XAMLX** file here?

Comment: Yes. It's uploaded. Btw I'm using Websites so it's FTP only.

Comment: You cannot remote desktop to an instance in Azure Websites. The only way to upload files is through FTp/WebDeploy/Git